# Click on Webpage tab if it is visible

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been trying to click on tab in a webpage using the code

```
Set P = D.FindElementByCss("a[href='#pro-content-pro']")
    P.Click
```

which works fine with the above code if the tab is visible in the webpage, if it is not visible then that is not going to work.. Below are the HTML codes

**When Visible**

```html
<li data-bind="attr:{ 'id': id }, click: onClick, visible: isVisible, css: {'active': isActive, 'disabled-control': !isEnabled() }" class="active">
                <a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" data-bind="attr:{ href: '#' + sectionId, id: linkId }, css: { 'disabled': !isEnabled() }" href="#pro-content-pro">
                    <span data-bind="text: title">Proforma</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

**When not visible**

```html
<li data-bind="attr:{ 'id': id }, click: onClick, visible: isVisible, css: {'active': isActive, 'disabled-control': !isEnabled() }" class="disabled-control">
                <a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" data-bind="attr:{ href: '#' + sectionId, id: linkId }, css: { 'disabled': !isEnabled() }" href="#pro-content-pro" class="disabled">
                    <span data-bind="text: title">Proforma</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Suggest me the correct code if the tab is not visible then skip else click on the tab if it is visible.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Selenium then try this

```
Set P = D.FindElementByCss("a[href='#pro-content-pro']")
    If P.Attribute("class")="disabled" Then
    Else    
        P.Click
    End If
```